# Update statement with ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having a hard time writing an `UPDATE` query that includes an `ORDER BY` clause.

Is this possible? I would appreciate any suggestions on how to do this.

This is a mock up of what I am trying to do:

```
UPDATE notes SET `note`='$note' WHERE `date` = (ORDER BY `date`  DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a column in your update statement. This [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e8362) shows you how to do it. Basically, you need to add `date` to your `order by` clause.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This did not work for me... it is essentially what I had posted in my original example :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this sql query:

```
UPDATE notes SET `note`='$note' WHERE `date` = (select `date` from notes ORDER BY DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, will give it a try and check back. I think your missing `date` after `ORDER BY`...

Comment: I think in mysql we can't use `select` statement in `update` query

Answer (score 0):

you dont' really need order by, basing your sample query.

```
Update .... 'date' = (select max('date') from notes)
```